# colvis jquery column visibility didn't work

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, view, datatables

Please help me to get the problem, js colvis not working in my project. This is source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var table;

$(document).ready(function() {

        //datatables
        table = $('#table').DataTable({

            "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
            "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
            "order": [], //Initial no order.
            // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('customer/ajax_list')?>",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function (data) {
                    data.salesnama = $('#salesnama').val();
                    data.type = $('#type').val();
                }
            },

            //Set column definition initialisation properties.
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [0], //first column / numbering column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
            ],

        });

    var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.ColVis(table); //initial colvis
    $('#colvis').html(colvis.button()); //add colvis button to div with id="colvis"

});
</script>
```

The problem is button colvis didnt show, I think this code same with sample in datatable source

**this code view button colvis**

```
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="colvis"> tes</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see that you are including the `buttons` and `dom` option which should be included for `colvis` to work, add this to your current script:

```
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'colvis'
    ]
```

Remember to include the need it librarys.
Here a really basic example from [official page](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/simple.html):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'colvis'
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I try to include this code to my script, but this didn't work

Comment: Hi, Could you be more specific with what is not workingm does an error appear on the console or something?